# How to recognize "0,0" "00,0" as zero inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote below javascript function to avoid saving zero(0 , 0.00) inputs in project. It works fine but for inputs like "0,00" "0,0" it does not recognize them as zero input.

I also tried "1,00" as inputs but it also save as zero without failing.

```
if ($('.the_input_text').val() <= 0) {
        error_msg_generator('#ErrorDiv', 'error',  msgError);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: one way is that, add a rejax to avoid entering any stupid combination of 0 in textbox itself

Comment: The browser will be using your locale (usually set by OS) to determine how to automatically parse text to numbers. so either `,` or `.` will work automatically but never both.

Comment: Actually the error occurred in sweden site. They are using , instead of . to show decimals. I have not considered culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace()` to change `,` to`.` and then use `parseFloat()` to convert it to a number

```
if (parseFloat($('.the_input_text').val().replace(',' , '.')) <= 0) {
    error_msg_generator('#ErrorDiv', 'error',  msgError);
    return;
}
```

**Edit:** You need to use `replace(',' , '.')` because if you don't use, `'0,5'` will result in `'0'`not `0.5`as said in the comments by vlaz

Comment: i think parseFloat will be better

Comment: As with the other answer - `parseFloat("0,50")` results in `0` instead of the correct `0.5`.